# Can I read a specific kafka offset from consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, consumer

I am trying to read from the specific offset number and write into HDFS

I have tried from specific partition it's working but offset not working

I need to get the specific offset values
for eg ..latest offset is 5000 but i need to read offset 3000 only not from 3000 to 5000

Answer (score 0):

You can use **seek(TopicPartition, long)** method of Consumer, and then just process first record and then break the loop.

Let me know if you need additional help.

For more information on method click [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/2.3.0)

Comment: Thanks for your replay...Could you please add the piece of lines in my piece of code .I have the code for get specific partition import java.util
import java.util.Properties
import java.util.regex.Pattern

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object KafkaConsumerAssign0App {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val  props = new Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers","abc900001.ABC.com.au:9092")
props.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")

Comment: props.put("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "kafka")
 props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
 props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
 props.put("group.id", "testconsumergroup")
val consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props)
val tp0 = new TopicPartition("topic_ravi,1")
val tp1 = new TopicPartition("topic",1)
val topics = List[TopicPartition](tp0,tp1)

Comment: consumer.assign(topics.asJava)
while(true){
val records = consumer.poll(10)
for(record<-records.asScala){
println("Key: "+record.key() +", Value: "+record.value() +", Offset: "+record.offset() )
}    }
    consumer.close()// close in finally block
  }}